# Permenantly Increase MTU for bridged interface on RHEL 7

Tags: networking, rhel, network-interface, bridge

I'm using RHEL 7 and need to increase the MTU of a bridged interface to 3000. The bridged interface (br0) only uses one physical NIC (em2). Within em2's network-script I have the lines:

```
MTU=3000
BRIDGE=br0
```

and within br0's network-script I have the line:

```
MTU=3000
```

The bridged interface is functioning (can communicate over the em2 NIC), however the MTU remains at 1500 for both em2 and br0.

I can temporarily set em2's MTU using `ifconfig em2 mtu 3000`, but attempting to do so with br0 fails:

```
SIOCSIFMT: Invalid argument
```

Which after some searching it is an error that commonly occurs when the hardware does not support the given MTU. I tried `ifconfig br0 down;ifconfig br0 up` before setting the MTU with no luck, which isn't surprising given that `ifconfig br0 down; ifconfig br0` still states the MTU of 1500.

I'm guessing that at boot time br0 is setting it's highest available MTU, and that because at boot em2's MTU is 1500 br0 cannot exceed that. If I can get em2's MTU up to 3000 at boot time I might be able to raise br0 as well, however the setting in the network-script seems to have no effect.

Does anyone have experience setting the MTU of an interface in RHEL 7? My research suggests it should be the same as previous versions, and I have set the MTU successfully using this method in earlier versions of RHEL, just not with bridges.

EDIT: I should also mention these interfaces are static, not DHCP, so they would not be getting their MTU from a DHCP server.